How to make the script iterate over objects not only in a given collection, but also in all collections nested in this collection, and so on?
There is such a script:
for obj in bpy.data.collections['MainCollection'].objects:
    file.write("[{}]\n".format(
        obj.name
    ))

How can I do to get the names of objects from the whole tree of this collection?

Use children_recursive:
collection_name = 'Collection'

from bpy import data as D

root_collection = D.collections[collection_name]
collections = [root_collection] + root_collection.children_recursive
for col in collections:
    print(f"Iterating over collection: {col.name}")
    for ob in col.objects:
        print(ob.name)


Thank you! This is probably the perfect answer.

You can use collection.children to iterate through child collections of a given collection
for col in bpy.data.collections['Collection'].children:
    for obj in col.objects:
        print(obj.name)


Thanks! I combined this with the cycle and now it's what I need!
